# Getting wrong scale on georeferenced TIFF in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, scale

I just georeferenced a map of Iceland using the ISN93 coordinate system. It looks like it was successful since when I transform some random coordinates to WGS84 and compare them to Google Maps it does match.

For the raster image I used a map 1:2'000'000 that I downloaded from the cadastral office, so it should be accurate.

But when I try to view it on QGIS I need a scale of at least 1:10'000'000'000 to see it.

Why is that?

Comment: Did you load your GCP points from a file, or input them manually by clicking on the raster and then on a base map? If you used a base map, are you sure the base map is accurate?

Comment: Did you give the coordinates of GCPs in metres?

Comment: Zoltan, that's actually a good question... I really don't know.

That's what i put in - if it helps (I used the ISN93 coordinates).
64° 0.842'N, 16° 40.622'W (ISN93: 613591, 392170)

Comment: Note that `ISN93 EPSG:4659` uses decimal degrees, while `ISN93/Lambert 1993 EPSG:3057` uses meters.